# Asp.net Core options class needs class instance as parameter, what if the class uses DI references?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

In startup.cs I have

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("RequireSomething", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new SomeRequirement()));
});
```

What if the SomeRequirement -class needs a class that is only available through dependency injection, like below. I can't/don't want to instantiate SomeRequirement.

```
public class SomeRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<SomeRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    ISomething _something;
    public SomeRequirement(ISomething something)
    {
        _something = something;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SomeRequirement requirement)
    {
        //TODO Do stuff
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest there are two solution for this.

1. I assume that you have concrete implementation of `ISomething`. If you knew that that initialize that and pass it to parameter as parameter. This is short and sweet solution.
2. Second solution is bit awkward.

   - Default DI Container available in ASP.net Core does not support property injection.
   - Instead of using Default DI Container try to use [Autofac](https://autofac.org/) or some other DI Container that support property injection.

Update 1: Possible Solution. ( Using Default DI of ASP.net Core)

```
public class SomeRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<SomeRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{

    ISomething _something;
    public SomeRequirement(ISomething something)
    {
        _something = something;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SomeRequirement requirement)
    {
        //TODO Do stuff
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public interface ISomething
{

}

public class Something : ISomething
{

}
```

And In ConfigureService

```
services.AddSingleton<ISomething, Something>();
services.AddScoped(typeof(SomeRequirement));
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {                
options.AddPolicy("RequireSomething", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<SomeRequirement>()));
            });
```